# C++ singleton in constructor

Tags: c++, design-patterns, memory-leaks, singleton

Is this possible?

```
class A {
    static A *instance = NULL;

public:
    A () {
        if (instance) {
            this = instance;
        } else {
            instance = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Does it have leak memory?

Do I need to oveload `new` operator?

Comment: I recommend you examine this answer which describes how to make a singleton: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3807729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Overlooking your compiler errors, your class won't work.

[@Galik has provided invaluable sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336727/c-singleton-in-constructor#comment67928461_40336727) for how you'd actually want to construct a singleton. But let's look at yours.

```
class A {
    static A *instance = NULL; // NULL isn't even a thing, but assuming you mean nullptr you can't assign a static like this

public:
    A () {
        if (instance) {
            this = instance; // this can't be assigned
        } else {
            instance = this; // this is correct
        }
    }
};
```

Which would give you the following:

```
class A {
    static A *instance;

public:
    A () {
        // if there's no instance, this is the one we'll use
        if (!instance) {
            instance = this;
        }
    }
};

A* A::instance = nullptr;
```

Which doesn't stop you from constructing more than one anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. If the constructor is exposed and called, a new object of `A` is inevitably created. The most elegant and widely used implementations of C++ singleton classes use static methods to return the single static instance, while hiding (e.g. make `private` accessible) the constructor.

Here's an example:

```
class A {
private:
    static A *instance_; // use nullptr since C++11
    A() {}
public:
    static A& instance() {
        if (!instance_)
            instance_ = new A();
        return *instance_;
    }
};

A* A::instance_ = nullptr;
```

Comment: If you have to show Singleton, use the [Meyers' one](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/2713/singleton-design-pattern/11369/thread-safe-singeton#t=201610310900159732795).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a value for this